# Dealing with Corruption

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, restore, corruption

I started getting **Error 823** alerts from my SQL Server. When I checked SQL Server error log, I found lots of this:

> A read of the file 'path\to\my\file.ndf' at offset 0x00000d5f850000
> succeeded after failing 1 time(s) with error: torn page (expected
> signature: 0x00000000; actual signature: 0x06004840). Additional
> messages in the SQL Server error log and system event log may provide
> more detail. This error condition threatens database integrity and
> must be corrected. Complete a full database consistency check (DBCC
> CHECKDB). This error can be caused by many factors; for more
> information, see SQL Server Books Online.
>
> Operating system error 'incorrect pageid (expected 18:290592;
> actual 37888:-2080349952)' resulted from attempt to read the
> following: sort run page (18:290592), in file 'path\to\my\file.ndf',
> in database with ID 8. Sort is retrying the read.

The first thing I checked was the table `msdb.dbo.suspect_pages` - There were a few entries in this table.

The database was also in a suspect state.
I used DBCC page to check a few of the page types affected and found IAM & PFS pages were affected.
At this point, I knew I needed to restore.

I attempted a restore of the latest backup, got this error:

> SQL Server detected a logical consistency-based I/O error:
> incorrect checksum (expected: 0x79266f9b; actual: 0x79262f9b). It
> occurred during a read of page (121:0) in database ID 8 at offset
> 0000000000000000 in file 'path\to\my\file.ndf'.  Additional messages
> in the SQL Server error log or system event log may provide more
> detail. This is a severe error condition that threatens database
> integrity and must be corrected immediately. Complete a full database
> consistency check (DBCC CHECKDB). This error can be caused by many
> factors; for more information, see SQL Server Books Online.

I then attempted another 2 restores, each with an older backup and got these errors:

> Invalid header value from a page. Run DBCC CHECKDB to check for a
> data corruption.
>
> One or more files do not match the primary file of the database. If
> you are attempting to attach a database, retry the operation with the
> correct files.  If this is an existing database, the file may be
> corrupted and should be restored from a backup.

My last option was to attempt to restore the database to another server. This worked

Has anyone has disk problems to the point that a restore fails with corruption type messages?

I'm inclined to think that the disks on my server are completely messed?

Environment is SQL 2008 R2 running on a physical server.

Thanks

Comment: If the disks themselves are having issues then all bets are off. Can you add to your post the SMART ouput from the drives (use `smartctl` or CrystalDiskInfo or similar). Any reason you are using 2008R2 which is now well out of support?

Comment: It also doesn't have to be a disk issue, filter drivers and bad memory can also display these same issues. If restoring the data from the same backups (which presumably reside on the these disks) works then it seems local to this server.

Comment: The backups don't reside on this server. Using an external application for backups/restores